# How to create organization structure using codeigniter and json

Tags: json, codeigniter-3, organizational-chart

I have task to create a organization structure from database using codeigniter and json. I got constraint. the script isn't working.

Are there any suggestions for create it??

This is my database (organization) :

```html
- table_org
id    urutan     name       title
1        1       aaaa      Head of Logistic
2        2      bbbbbb     Division Logistic
3        3      ccccccc    Staff/Employees, etc...
```

```html
View :

<body>    
    <div id="people"></div>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
  
  var readUrl = "http://localhost/Codeg/struktur_org/";
  
  $.getJSON(readUrl, function(people) {  
   $('#people').getOrgChart({
    theme: "helen",
    primaryColumns: ["name", "title"],
    imageColumn: "image",
    linkType: "M",
    editable: false,
    dataSource: people 
   });
  });
    </script> 
</body>
```

```html
Controller :

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI

class Struktur_org extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('struktur_model');
 }
 
 public function index()//may be index() or something else.Rename this funciton name as yours
 {
  echo json_encode( $this->struktur_model->getMember() );
  $this->load->view('struktur_org');
 }

}
```

```html
Model :

<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Struktur_model extends CI_Model {

 function __construct()
    {
  parent::__construct();
 }
 
 function getMember(){
  
        $query = $this->db->get('org');
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor second column should be parrent ID. Here is an example

```html
- table_org
id    urutan     name       title
1        null       aaaa      Head of Logistic
2        1      bbbbbb     Division Logistic
3        1      ccccccc    Staff/Employees, etc...
```